# Select from/sender address

Tags: office-js, outlook-web-addins

In an Outlook web add-in attached to a [Compose Scenario](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/compose-scenario) context, we can change the message recipients (e.g. `to`) as follows:

```js
Office.context.mailbox.item.to.setAsync(
[
  {
    displayName: "Allie Bellew",
    emailAddress: "allieb@contoso.com"
  }
], result => console.log(result));
```

[image: From and to addresses in compose view]

However, the `from` property appears to be readonly, even though in the Outlook web GUI I can pretty much set it to arbitrary values by clicking on the `From` button (although not all values may be accepted by our mail server of course). Is there a way to modify the sender as well from an Outlook web add-in?

I already tried `item.internetHeaders.setAsync` but that seems intended only for `X-` prefixed custom headers, so the following call succeeds but has no effect, neither in the GUI nor the sent message.

```js
item.internetHeaders.setAsync({ From: "jane.doe@binkmail.com" }, result => console.log(result));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently the set API for From address is not a part of the product. We track Outlook add-in feature requests on [our Tech Community Page](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-365-developer-platform/idb-p/Microsoft365DeveloperPlatform). Please submit your request there and choose the appropriate label(s). Feature requests on Tech Community are considered, when we go through our planning process.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying. I submitted a request here:
https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-365-developer-platform/changing-the-from-sender-address-in-a-compose-scenario/idi-p/2374971